Angular 18 animation - state change works but no transition
I want to achieve my first animation in Angular 18.
The state change works but I do not get the transition animation.
Component TS / @Component > animations:
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChannelComponent, WorkspaceComponent, ThreadComponent],
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrl: './main.component.scss',
  animations: [
    trigger('toggleWorkspace', [
      state(
        'open',
        style({
          opacity: '1',
        })
      ),
      state(
        'closed',
        style({
          opacity: '0.5'
        })
      ),
      transition('open<=>closed', animate('5s')),
       
    ])
  ]

Component TS / class export:
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  showWorkspaceMenu: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.showWorkspaceMenu = true;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  toggle() {
    this.showWorkspaceMenu = !this.showWorkspaceMenu;
  }

}

A click event starts the toggle() which changes the value of showWorkspaceMenu which triggers the animation for the section.
<section [@toggleWorkspace]="showWorkspaceMenu ?  'closed' : 'open'">
          <app-workspace></app-workspace>
      </section> 

Component HTML:
<div class="wrapper">
  <span (click)="toggle()" class="toggle-btn">
      @switch(showWorkspaceMenu) {
        @case (false) {
       <span>open Workspace Menu</span>
      }
        @default {
        <span>close Workspace Menu</span>
          }
      }
  </span>
  <section class="header"> 
          <input placeholder="Devspace durchsuchen" class="flex-item2" type="text">
          <div class="flex-item1 user-info">UserInfo</div>
  </section>
  <section  class="content"> 
      <section  [@toggleWorkspace]="showWorkspaceMenu ?  'closed' : 'open'">
          <app-workspace></app-workspace>
      </section>  
  </section>
</div>

I have imported provideAnimations in main.ts. I already tried the same with provideAnimationsAsync from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async' .
main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { provideAnimations} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,  {
providers: [
provideAnimations(),
...appConfig.providers]
})
.catch((err) => console.error(err))


Update: Solved.
I deleted 'provideAnimationsAsync'(noop)' in providers in app.config.ts, animation works

If you are using SSR, then you can wrap the animation in a @defer block, so that it happens only on the browser.
...
@defer() {
    <section  [@toggleWorkspace]="showWorkspaceMenu ?  'closed' : 'open'">
          <app-workspace></app-workspace>
    </section>  
}
...


Your transition is too large, this gives you the illusion that the animation does not happen. It just takes 5 second to complete, instead try a smaller interval like 0.5s.
transition('open<=>closed', animate('0.5s')),

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks. the state change from opacity: 1 to opacity: 0.5 and back works.
My problem is that it only switches without animating the transition.

@IngoHe In my stackblitz it switches, along with the animation

Yes, that confuses me. In my app it doesn't.

@IngoHe do you have SSR enabled? try wrapping the animation inside @defer block then, so that the animation happens only inside browser and not on the server

i just tried this, but i am not really sure if that is what you mean.
<input  @defer [@toggleWorkspace]="showWorkspaceMenu ?  'closed' : 'open'"  placeholder="Devspace durchsuchen" type="text">
But I also have no server.ts and no entries like @nguniversal/express-engine in my project.

@IngoHe what version of angular are you using?

Angular v 18.2.0

@IngoHe updated my answer, with usage of @defer block

unfortunately it is still not working
@defer() {
    <section  [@toggleWorkspace]="showWorkspaceMenu ?  'closed' : 'open'">
      <app-workspace></app-workspace>
  </section>
}


@IngoHe ok I'm out of ideas, try inspect element and check if the css is applied properly, you might find the culprit
